# Error:(81, 0) getMainOutputFile is no longer supported. Use getOutputFileName if you need to determine the file name of the output.

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to customize the build process using below code

```
   android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            def appName = "MyApplication.apk"

            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, appName)
            }
        }
```

But from android studio 3.0 it not working I am getting below error

**Error:(81, 0) getMainOutputFile is no longer supported.  Use getOutputFileName if you need to determine the file name of the output.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig getSigningConfig()
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            def date = new Date();
            def formattedDate = date.format('dd MMMM yyyy')
            variant.outputs.all {
                def newApkName
                newApkName = "MyApp-${variant.versionName}, ${formattedDate}.apk"
                outputFileName = newApkName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the support:)

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the [Android Gradle Plugin v3 migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/new-android-plugin-migration.html#variant_api):

> Using the Variant API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the
>   new plugin. It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK
>   name during build time, as shown below:

```
// If you use each() to iterate through the variant objects,
// you need to start using all(). That's because each() iterates
// through only the objects that already exist during configuration time—
// but those object don't exist at configuration time with the new model.
// However, all() adapts to the new model by picking up object as they are
// added during execution.

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "${project.name}-${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```

There will be a new api for more complex use cases than renaming the output file name.

Comment: Thank you for the support:)